# Integrate a 'suspend' shell command into a Python script or not?

Tags: shell, python

I run a Python script from a shell script because I suspend the system after the Python script is finished with this shell command :

```bash
    [ -t 0 ] || systemctl suspend
```

The shell script is run as a cron job. The test is for debugging and can be replaced by an argument.

Is it better to keep it this way or is it better to get rid of the shell script and use `subprocess.run(['systemctl','suspend'])` call in Python?

For simplicity (only one file to manage), I'd prefer the latter method: only one Python script. But I wonder if this's the right way.

I know that for performance reasons, it's better to avoid system calls and that there're limitations (no piping for example).

In this particular case, because of the `suspend` command, the Python script won't be terminated properly. Is that an issue?

Comment: Maybe use `os.system(cmd)`. Or do all the things in shell.

Comment: My questions is : is it better, or at least the same? I can't do everything in the shell unfortunately.

Comment: Hard to say which is better. and BTW I did RDBMS in `bash` :)

Comment: Well, the integrated Python script seems to work fine. However, I'm keeping both shell and Python scripts separated, as believe it's cleaner.